# Angular Calendar integration not able to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to include angular ui-calendar component. I followed step from the site
1. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar
and 
2. http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Fullcalendar-Walk-through-with-AngularJS

Installed the components through

```
bower install angular-ui-calendar
```

Loaded components in html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css"/>
```

Included dependency into app

```
var app = angular.module('myCalendarApp', ['ui.calendar'])
```

In UI inserted like

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
```

In controller created static events and configuration

```
$scope.eventSources = [];
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
            left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.eventClick
    }
};      
$scope.eventClick = function(event){ 
    alert("Clicked event === "+event.title);
};
var events = [
    {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date('Sun Dec 17 2017 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)')},
    {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date('Thu Dec 21 2017 10:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'),end: new Date('Thu Dec 21 2017 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)')},
    {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date('Mon Dec 4 2017 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'),allDay: false}
];
$scope.eventSources = [events];
```

When I tried to verify the calendar in browser it is throwing following error

```
TypeError: calendar.fullCalendar is not a function
at Scope.scope.initCalendar (calendar.js:286)
at Object.fn (calendar.js:358)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15896)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
at WindowsCtrl.window.showDialog.$scope.showDialog (controller.js:690)
at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (VM4670 windows:1)
```

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you load the fullcalendar.js file?

Comment: Yeah. Seems only the css is included. Where is `<script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>`?

Comment: I have included all the necessary script and css files
@rolodex

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all the dependencies and wire it from your HTML

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css"/>
<!-- jquery, moment, and angular have to get included before fullcalendar -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/gcal.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have included all the necessary script and css files

Answer (score 0):

thank you every one who given suggestion to solve the issue.

I solved the issue.
There is some issue in angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js file. In init and destroy methods they are creating the component by using angular.element method but if I change it with jQuery it solved the issue.

reference : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/267